# How can I reference individual MIDI events using the python-midi module?

Tags: python, midi

I'm using [this python module](https://github.com/vishnubob/python-midi) (for python 2) to try and access an individual MIDI event. So far I have

```
import midi  
pattern = midi.read_midifile('Conquest of Paradise.mid')  
print pattern
```

This prints a LOT of midi events. But `len(pattern)` returns the value 13 (which is a LOT less). How can I iterate over `pattern` to access any `midi.NoteOnEvents`? I've tried reading the source code but I guess I don't know nearly enough python.

EDIT: User CL has pointed out the 13 refers to tracks.
So I figure I can iterate over the MIDI file like so:

```
trackCount = len(pattern)
eventCount = 0

for i in range(trackCount):
    for j in range(i):
        print(pattern[i][j].name)
        eventCount += 1

print(eventCount)
```

But now this gives `eventCount = 78`, when it's definitely a lot more than 78. Also of all the names printed, none of them are `NoteOnEvent` or `NoteOffEvent`.

Comment: I guess that file has 13 tracks.

Comment: Just went through it and you're right, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating the pattern incorrectly in the inner loop, try this:

```
trackCount = len(pattern)
eventCount = 0

for i in range(trackCount):
    for j in range(len(pattern[i])):
        print(pattern[i][j].name)
        eventCount += 1

print(eventCount)
```

Or, even better:

```
eventCount = 0

for p in pattern:
    for event in p:
        print(event.name)
        eventCount += 1

print(eventCount)
```